# Expand parent height with child height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fix a problem. The child elements are using position absolute and therefore I can't use `clear:both`

So basically, this is what I need to do.

get height of child div once the content inside it is loaded. then set the height of the parent. 
this is the site. ---> http://coteau-du-lac.com/
parent div ---> `.crown-vc-area`
child div ---> `#rev_slider_1_1`

Comment: So can you do `$('.crown-vc-area').height( $('#rev_slider_1_1').height() );` ?

Comment: I did, turns out the rev slider isn't loaded by that time and it returns me a zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `overflow: hidden` in your css rule for the parent.

```
.crown-vc-area {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I did already. it's there but the layout breaks at higher resolutions. 1700*800
1920*1080

Comment: According to Nikolay's comment it might just be that you need to call that `.height()` function at the correct time. Can you put in in a callback after `#rev_slider_1_1` gets it's data?